# Как установить драйвер для PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, pyqt5

Я начал работу с PyQt5 и Postgre
Запустил код в pycharm, выдало системную ошибку
Запустил код в cmd, выдало следующее:

```
QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
Connected to database
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
```

Полез разбираться, на всех форумах пишут очень сложно про "сборку драйверов", я ничего не понял, так как прежде с подобным не сталкивался и плохо разбираюсь в сис.администрировании.
Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Comment: ну не используйте. попробуйте psycopg2, sqlalchemy. принципы те же. сделать запрос - получить ответ с данными.